# Capture a captcha image

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, rselenium

I am trying to scrape data from the Peruvian Electronic System for Government Procurement and Contracting ([SEACE](https://prodapp2.seace.gob.pe/seacebus-uiwd-pub/buscadorPublico/buscadorPublico.xhtml)) (using RSelenium) and I have succeeded until I try to capture the URL from the Captcha image. The problem that I encounter is that the link for the captcha has the extension "dynamiccontent.properties.xhtml" (See next screenshot), but not a "JPEG", "JPG" or "PNG" extension.

[image: Screenshot from SEACE]

I would like to get the URL from the captcha image in one of these extensions (JPEG, JPG or PNG) using R, any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: You probably can't do this, as the captcha is dynamically created. There is no image file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, what does this mean?, could I highlight this element and take a screenshot with RSelenium?

Comment: That might be your best chance, but I don't know how as I'm not much into scraping. However, it is intentionally hard to download CAPTCHAs in order to avoid circumventing them.

Comment: @mhovd The image is dynamically generated *by the server*, so downloading it using the URL from the source (plus the appropriate cookies) should work just fine. Captchas generally don’t attempt to protect against being downloaded (because that’s quite simply impossible due to how HTTP works) — they protect against being automatically *solved*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Thanks for your answer. Could you give me an advice about how can I download using the URL please?, I haven't been able to do this using the URL obtained from the screenshot above. FYI, I have been able to select the element in RSelenium with this code:
 "remDr$findElement(using = 'id', "tbBuscador:idFormBuscarProceso:captchaImg")
", but the image is not seen.

Comment: @Enki Can’t you grab the tag’s `src` attribute and download that? What the URL on the server is called is irrelevant. Beyond that I can’t really help since I’ve never worked with Selenium.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I tried that but the image doesnt download, maybe I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 4):

You CAN get the captcha image using Rselenium. But you require some image processing along with it. Since the captcha is generated dynamically, you need to take a screenshot of the page, then crop the image such that only the captcha is left. (try playing with the dimension argument of the cropping function to get it just right)

While doing so, make the window size large so that the resolution is good.

For cropping the image, you will need some trial and error. You can use packages *imager* or *magick* for the cropping bit.

```
library(RSelenium)
library(magick)
library(dplyr)
url<-"https://prodapp2.seace.gob.pe/seacebus-uiwd-pub/buscadorPublico/buscadorPublico.xhtml"

#### Selenium server
## For Firefox

rd<- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",port = 4581L)
remDr <- rd$client
remDr$open()


##Open url
remDr$navigate(url)

remDr$setWindowSize(2000,1600)

remDr$screenshot(display = FALSE, file = "captcha.png")


final_cap<-image_read("captcha.png") %>% 
  image_crop(.,"200X100+500+500") 

plot(final_cap)
```

Please do note that I don't support any illegal captcha breaking - they were designed to keep robots out!

[image: Captcha Captured!]